# How to correctly escape double quote (") inside a json string in Python

Tags: python, json

In the json file double quotes are escaped, am not sure what is that am missing here

```
import json
s = '{"title": "Fetching all Jobs from \"host_name\"."}'
j = json.loads(s)
print(j)

ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 36 (char 35)
```

Comment: What "file" are you referring to? See [mcve]

Comment: A file containing `{"title": "Fetching all Jobs from \"host_name\"."}` is valid json. The problem with your string is that the backslashes are also a python literal string escape. You can fix it in your example with raw strings, but its not needed in a file that you read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need a string in the first place?

```
s = {"title": 'Fetching all Jobs from "host_name".'}

# If you want a string, then here
import json
j = json.dumps(s)
print(j)
```

The recycled value looks like so

```
{"title": "Fetching all Jobs from \"host_name\"."}
>>> s2 = r'{"title": "Fetching all Jobs from \"host_name\"."}'
>>> json.loads(s2)
{'title': 'Fetching all Jobs from "host_name".'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using r strings will help you escape the inner quotes in the json string.

```
import json
s = r'{"title": "Fetching all Jobs from \"host_name\"."}'
j = json.loads(s)
print(j)
```

But I am not sure if this is best practice.

Comment: I've updated the answer.
You can get the desired result by using raw strings, and escaping the inner quotes. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals for more information.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways I know of to handle it, the first is to escape the '\':

```
s = '{"title": "Fetching all Jobs from \\"host_name\\"."}'
```

The second is to use a raw string literal:

```
s = r'{"title": "Fetching all Jobs from \"host_name\"."}'
```

note the 'r' in front of the string.

Answer (score 0):

if you use `json` in this way, it might work for you:

```
import json

 s = 'my string with "double quotes" and more'
json.dumps(s)
'"my string with \\"double quotes\\" and more"'
```

Comment: I ran this in the python shell and got `SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier` in `s = ‘my string with “double quotes” and more’`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

this wiil help you

```
>>> import json
>>> s= json.dumps('{"title": "Fetching all Jobs from \"host_name\"."}')
>>> j=json.loads(s)
>>> print(j)
{"title": "Fetching all Jobs from "host_name"."}
```